# How can I skip the first line of items from a CSV?

Tags: javascript, angular, csv, typescript

I am trying to skip over the first line or headers of the items from a CSV in the following function:

```
importFoods() {
  var csv= `foodname,category
    Banana,Produce
    Apple,Produce`;

  var lines = csv.split("\n");
  console.log('lines',lines);
  for(var l in lines) {
    var cols = lines[l].split(",")
    console.log('cols',cols);
    //0 is foodname
    //1 is category
    var globallistData = {
      foodname: cols[0],
      category: cols[1],
    };

    console.log(globallistData)
    const globalfoods = this.db.list('/globalfoods');
    globalfoods.push(globallistData);
  }
}
```

What would be the best way to do this using Angular or Typescript / Javascript?

Comment: `lines.shift()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
importFoods(){
   var csv= `foodname,category
       Banana,Produce
       Apple,Produce`;

   var lines = csv.split("\n");
   console.log('lines',lines);
   for(var l=1; l<lines.length ;l++){
          var cols = lines[l].split(",")
          console.log('cols',cols);
         //0 is foodname
         //1 is category
         ....
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You was so close! Here is the simple solution via `forEach` iteration method and `join` new array items:

```js
function importFoods() {
  var csv= `foodname,category
    Banana,Produce
    Apple,Produce`;
    
  var newCsv = [];

  var lines = csv.split("\n");
  lines.forEach(function(item, i) {
    if(i !== 0) newCsv.push(item);
  })
  
  newCsv = newCsv.join("\n");
  console.log(newCsv);
}

importFoods()
```